# Executing batfiles from the IIS hosted website

Tags: batch-file, file-permissions

This is regarding executing bat files from the hosted website.

When I try to execute the batfile and I run it in Visual Studio locally
it runs perfectly (localhost), but when it comes to to execute from hosted web (public-ip) (Same project location) it fails (Control simply pass through Process.Start() method)and does nothing.

I have given good enough time over this issue now hoping some full proof
Solution.I checked Event Logs and there were

- **distributed Com
  errors (10016,10010) while attempting this batch file execution.**

As per my knowledge its permission issue and I have already made few changes on reg level (as per AppId,Clsid) but no re-leaf.

Sys:Windows 8 Single language

Comment: Project developed in ASP.net mvc (.net)

Answer (score 0):

As I noticed this issue of permissions Please try below code

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psinfo =
   new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@“C:\temp.bat”);
 psinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 psinfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 psinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 System.Diagnostics.Process lstFiles;
 lstFiles= System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psinfo);
 System.IO.StreamReader myOutput = lstFiles.StandardOutput;
 lstFiles.WaitForExit(2000);
 if (lstFiles.HasExited)
  {
  string output = myOutput.ReadToEnd();
  this.processResults.Text = output;
 }
```

Hope this will help. You also check firewall, Probably a firewall issue. so its relates to the operating system and not asp.net.